# Have text fields show up when radio button is clicked in rails + javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, radio-button

Hi I'm trying to have the date text fields show up if a radio box 'custom' is clicked, and disappear when one of the other two radio boxes are clicked.

So far here is my form:

```
//Default radio buttons
<%= radio_button_tag 'set_start', 14 %>
<%= label :set_start, 'Biweekly' %>
<%= radio_button_tag  'set_start', 30 %>
<%= label :set_start, 'Monthly' %>

<%= radio_button_tag 'set_start', 0, {:class => "rad_but"} %>
<%= label :set_start, 'Custom' %>

//Button that only appears when custom is clicked
<div id='dates'>
    <%= label :starting, 'Start date'%>
    <%= text_field_tag 'starting', placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"%>   
    <br>
    <%= label :ending, 'End date' %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'ending', placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" %>
</div>
```

And here is my javascript so far (EDITED) :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="set_start"]').on('change', function(evt) {
   if (evt.target.value === "0") {
      console.log("hello");
      $('#dates').show();
   } else {
      console.log("world");
      $('#dates').hide();
   }
})
```

});

And my HTML:

```
<div class="form-inputs">



            <label for="set_start_Biweekly">Biweekly</label>
                <input type="radio" name="set_start" id="set_start_30" value="30">
            <label for="set_start_Monthly">Monthly</label>

                <input type="radio" name="set_start" id="set_start_0" value="0" checked="checked">
            <label for="set_start_Custom">Custom</label>

                <br>
            <br>

            <div id="dates">
              <label for="starting_Start date" class="active">Start date</label>
              <input type="text" name="starting" id="starting" value="MM/DD/YYYY">  
            <br>
              <label for="ending_End date" class="active">End date</label>
            <input type="text" name="ending" id="ending" value="MM/DD/YYYY">
            </div>


</div>
```

Currently, the dates are still showing, even by default too, and it's also not changing on the clicks. Is there a way I can move past this?

Comment: Since this appears to be an HTML/JS problem try posting the HTML generated from the ruby code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your generated HTML looks like this:

```html
<input type="radio" name="set_start" value="14"/>
<label>Biweekly</label>
<input type="radio" name="set_start" value="30"/>
<label>Monthly</label>
<input type="radio" name="set_start" value="0"/>
<label>Custom</label>

<div id="dates">
    <label>Start date</label>
    <input type='date' name='starting' placeholder='MM/DD/YYYY' />
    <br />
    <label>End date</label>
    <input type='date' name='ending' placeholder='MM/DD/YYYY' />
</div>
```

you can use the following jquery snippet

```js
$('input[name="set_start"]').on('change', function(evt) {
   if (evt.target.value === "0") {
      $('#dates').show();
   } else {
      $('#dates').hide();
   }
})
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/oy38hscu/)

Comment: Hmm, my HTML is like that, and I've added it to my javascript file with the document.ready function(), but it's still not working.

Comment: Code is tested in jsfiddle. "Still not working" is not an answer for someone who tries to help you. Try to explain what is not working (e.g. error messages received)

Comment: Hi, sorry for that. Thanks for the help. I am refreshing the page and it stays the same. Perhaps I'm not calling the Jquery library maybe?

Comment: The date inputs will be initially shown. You have to either hide them using CSS, or add an extra call to `$('#dates').hide();` when your document loads